# Mysql unix timestamp select

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with orders list. Each order have order date (timestamp 1331182800). For each order user can select automatic reorder by 30, 60 or 90 days (`reorder` field (int)).
I need sql for cron to select all orders, that have order date = date + reorder. (date order + 30 or 60 or 90 days). 
Can You help me with this?

Comment: order date is a unix timestamp, and reorder is a day number, aren't they?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() >= (order_time_col + (reorder_days_col * 86400))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL o.reorder DAY), '%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.date), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

edited to skip the seconds from the comparison. I don't have a MYSQL engine so some errors still could occur, if that was so I'm sorry about such inconvenient...

Comment: its returns me empty result. i have an order with order date 28 may 2012 (1338183074) in reorder field i put 2 My query is: SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL reorder DAY) = FROM_UNIXTIME(`ord_date`)

Comment: The query is also comparing the seconds and it doesn't obviously doesn't match; Update coming.

Comment: @Sebas `I don't have a MYSQL engine` - Allow me to introduce you to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ;-)

Comment: that was not your question ;) "order date = date + reorder"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE `date` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - reorder*86400; # returns all orders, `date` field of which is older than 90 days ago
```

Answer (score 0):

timestamp is number of seconds passed from 1st Jan 1970
so in order convert timestamp value to days one needs to multiply it with 60 * 60 * 24 (= 86400)